# Query related to CSS Selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am working on the following piece of code displaying the progress:

```css
ol.progress[data-steps="2"] li {
  width: 49%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="3"] li {
  width: 33%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="4"] li {
  width: 24%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="5"] li {
  width: 19%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="6"] li {
  width: 16%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="7"] li {
  width: 14%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="8"] li {
  width: 12%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="9"] li {
  width: 11%;
}

.progress {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.progress li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.progress .name,
.progress .description {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.progress .name {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.progress .step {
  border: 3px solid #b6b6b6;
  background-color: #b6b6b6;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 0;
}

.progress .step:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: #b6b6b6;
  border: 3px transparent;
  height: 0.2em;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.6em;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -2;
}

.progress .step:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: #1876d5;
  border: 3px transparent;
  height: 0.35em;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.55em;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progress li:first-of-type .step:before {
  display: none;
}

.progress li:last-of-type .step:after {
  display: none;
}

.progress .done .step {
  background-color: #1876d5;
  border: 3px solid #1876d5;
}

.progress .done .step:after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ol class="progress" id="test" data-steps="4">
    <li class="done">
      <span class="step"></span>
      <span class="name">Step 1</span>
      <span class="description">Foo</span>
    </li>
    <li class="done">
      <span class="step"></span>
      <span class="name">Step 2</span>
      <span class="description">Bar</span>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <span class="step"></span>
      <span class="name">Step 3</span>
      <span class="description">Baz</span>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <span class="step"></span>
      <span class="name">Step 4</span>
      <span class="description">Abc</span>
    </li>

  </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

I got this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzP6v.png) with the above code. Using CSS, I was trying the exclude the blue color between 2nd and 3rd step so that it remains grey color(similar to the one between step 3 and step 4). I tried below which is not working:

```
    .progress .step:last-of-type .step:before {
    display: none;
}
```

Is there any similar type of CSS that can be used to achieve this functionality. Thanks.

Comment: @Gad  thanks for your answer. But I was looking for the css that dynamically works irrespective of change in number of steps or changes to the css class of existing li. For example, if I add "done" class to the 3rd li  in my above code(i.e. <li class="done">), the progress indicator output becomes invalid. In general, if n steps are done( whose <li class="done">) then there must not be blue color progress line after nth step.

Comment: check I edited, now the dynamically you can use `.done` class name to control them

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your answer this will solve your issue just use [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#:%7E:text=The%20nth%2Dchild%20pseudo%2Dclass,Element%20indices%20are%201%2Dbased.) selector to exclude the blue color between 2nd and 3rd step.

### The following is an example

```css
ol.progress[data-steps="2"] li {
  width: 49%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="3"] li {
  width: 33%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="4"] li {
  width: 24%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="5"] li {
  width: 19%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="6"] li {
  width: 16%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="7"] li {
  width: 14%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="8"] li {
  width: 12%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="9"] li {
  width: 11%;
}

.progress {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.progress li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.progress .name,
.progress .description {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.progress .name {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.progress .step {
  border: 3px solid #b6b6b6;
  background-color: #b6b6b6;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 0;
}

.progress .step:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: #b6b6b6;
  border: 3px transparent;
  height: 0.2em;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.6em;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -2;
}

.progress .step:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: #1876d5;
  border: 3px transparent;
  height: 0.35em;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.55em;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progress li:first-of-type .step:before {
  display: none;
}


/*=========== added =====================*/

.progress li:nth-child(2) .step:before {
  display: none;
}

.progress li:nth-child(2) .step:after {
  display: none;
}


/*=========== added =====================*/

.progress li:last-of-type .step:after {
  display: none;
}

.progress .done .step {
  background-color: #1876d5;
  border: 3px solid #1876d5;
}

.progress .done .step:after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<ol class="progress" id="test" data-steps="4">
  <li class="done">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="name">Step 1</span>
    <span class="description">Foo</span>
  </li>
  <li class="done">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="name">Step 2</span>
    <span class="description">Bar</span>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="name">Step 3</span>
    <span class="description">Baz</span>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="name">Step 4</span>
    <span class="description">Abc</span>
  </li>

</ol>
```

And if you want some dynamic where you will use `.done` class name to control the steps without getting stuck with `nth-child` selector.

---

The following is an example where there is none of `li` elements have `.done` class name

```css
ol.progress[data-steps="2"] li {
  width: 49%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="3"] li {
  width: 33%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="4"] li {
  width: 24%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="5"] li {
  width: 19%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="6"] li {
  width: 16%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="7"] li {
  width: 14%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="8"] li {
  width: 12%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="9"] li {
  width: 11%;
}

.progress {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.progress li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.progress .name,
.progress .description {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.progress .name {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.progress .step {
  border: 3px solid #b6b6b6;
  background-color: #b6b6b6;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 0;
}

.progress .step:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: #b6b6b6;
  border: 3px transparent;
  height: 0.2em;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.6em;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -2;
}

.progress .done .step:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: #1876d5;
  border: 3px transparent;
  height: 0.35em;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.55em;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progress li:first-of-type .step:before,
.progress li:last-of-type .step:after {
  display: none;
}

.progress .done .step {
  background-color: #1876d5;
  border: 3px solid #1876d5;
}

.progress .done .step:after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<ol class="progress" id="test" data-steps="4">
  <li class="">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="name">Step 1</span>
    <span class="description">Foo</span>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="name">Step 2</span>
    <span class="description">Bar</span>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="name">Step 3</span>
    <span class="description">Baz</span>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="name">Step 4</span>
    <span class="description">Abc</span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

---

The following is an example where there **first** and **third** `li` have `.done` class name

```css
ol.progress[data-steps="2"] li {
  width: 49%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="3"] li {
  width: 33%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="4"] li {
  width: 24%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="5"] li {
  width: 19%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="6"] li {
  width: 16%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="7"] li {
  width: 14%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="8"] li {
  width: 12%;
}

ol.progress[data-steps="9"] li {
  width: 11%;
}

.progress {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.progress li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.progress .name,
.progress .description {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.progress .name {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.progress .step {
  border: 3px solid #b6b6b6;
  background-color: #b6b6b6;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 0;
}

.progress .step:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: #b6b6b6;
  border: 3px transparent;
  height: 0.2em;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.6em;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -2;
}

.progress .done .step:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: #1876d5;
  border: 3px transparent;
  height: 0.35em;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.55em;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progress li:first-of-type .step:before,
.progress li:last-of-type .step:after {
  display: none;
}

.progress .done .step {
  background-color: #1876d5;
  border: 3px solid #1876d5;
}

.progress .done .step:after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<ol class="progress" id="test" data-steps="4">
  <li class="done">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="name">Step 1</span>
    <span class="description">Foo</span>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="name">Step 2</span>
    <span class="description">Bar</span>
  </li>
  <li class="done">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="name">Step 3</span>
    <span class="description">Baz</span>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="name">Step 4</span>
    <span class="description">Abc</span>
  </li>
</ol>
```